# jQuery.text() set modifies more than get

Tags: jquery

Consider the following HTML, I want to change 'blah' to something else.

```
<span> 
  <img src="/i/f_spacer.gif" class="my_class"> 
  blah
</span>
```

Considering `$('.my_class').parent().text()` returns 'blah' and `.html()` returns everything - I thought something like this would work

```
$('.my_class').parent().text('foo');
```

but it turns it into

```
<span> 
  foo
</span>
```

Do I need to include a span around 'blah', or can I use some sort of pseudo-class to identify this text?

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Simply use `nextSibling.data`

```
$('.my_class')[0].nextSibling.data = "foo";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WH92U/)

Comment: to me this seems like it blend blends the jQuery & DOM universes in an arbitrary part of the tree. What's the advantage of this over .last()?

Answer (score 2):

You can use append().

for example `$('.my_class').parent().append('foo');`

Result:

```
<div class="myclass">
<span> 
  <img src="/i/f_spacer.gif" class="my_class"> 
  blah
  foo
</span>
</div>
```

Or you need to change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="myclass">
<span> 
  <img src="/i/f_spacer.gif" class="my_class"> 
  <span class="temptext">blah</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Now you can use this:

```
$('.my_class .temptext').text('foo');
```

Result:

```
<div class="myclass">
    <span> 
      <img src="/i/f_spacer.gif" class="my_class"> 
      <span class="temptext">foo</span>
    </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I realised that extra span would give flexibility, but why does .text() return just the text while .text('foo') overwrites the img tag as well?

Comment: Becouse, If you have this html `<span> 
foo      
<img src="/i/f_spacer.gif" class="my_class"> 
      bar
    </span>`
how text you will be set? `Foo` or `Bar`?
 JQuery developers entrusted this work to us

Comment: that's a good scenario. still confusing that getter diffent to setter

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with out modifying the DOM by,

```
$('.my_class').parent().contents().last()[0].nodeValue = "Foo";
```

But adding a  around that text would give you more feasibility while accessing it,

```
$('.my_class').next('span').text("Foo");
```

If you want to use the above snippet, then your html must be,

```
<span> 
  <img src="/i/f_spacer.gif" class="my_class"> 
  <span>blah</span>
</span>
```

Comment: `$('.my_class')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = 'foo'` works just as well.

Comment: @Blender Yeah. That's right. :) i was just tried to answer OP in his way.. :)

Comment: Those answer shows options very well, and I knew there must have been a way like .last() to get what I was chasing.

Answer (score 0):

Text that isn't surrounded by a tag is still a [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType). You're effectively asking to replace all the [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) nodes. Use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to retrieve all child nodes in an element, including text nodes:

```
var $parent = $('.my_class').parent();

var $contents = $parent.contents().filter(function (i, e) {
  return e.nodeType != 3;
});

$parent.text('foo').prepend($contents);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/VQkPw/

Comment: the text may still be a node, but why does .text('foo') treat the img tag as text if it doesn't get _returned_ in .text()?

Comment: Because internally, jQuery uses [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
$('.my_class').parent().contents().filter(function(){
     return this.nodeType !==1;
}).get(1).textContent = 'foo';
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WH92U/1/)

Comment: @ScottWe - not 1001 ways no one should be calculated there are n numbers of ways\

Comment: You should take which way is effective and fastest